# ActionBar compatibility available in

Tags: android

I'm starting a new android project, and want to support api 8 onwards. I'm looking at the ActionBar class, which is only available in api 11 onwards. The compatibility library has classes like "ActionBarDrawerToggle" as of the May 2013 release - but is there a standalone ActionBar compatibility class for us to use now?:

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

or do we still have to use ActionBarSherlock?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ActionBarSherlok. Which more easy to use, and works on all platforms.